# Magento - Remove Category Name from Product and Subcategory Meta Title

Tags: magento, title, meta-tags

I was wondering how to remove category name from subcategory and product page meta title. As of right now my meta titles for subcategory pages are:

> Subcategory Title - Category Title | Title Suffix

and for product pages:

> Product Name - Subcategory Title - Category Title | Title Suffix.

I'd like it to be in the following structure for subcategories:

> Subcategory Title | Title Suffix

and for product page:

> Product Name | Title Suffix

Answer (score 1):

**With out changing any code,**

Via the admin site each category has the field "page_title" and each product has the field "meta_title" (under the tab "Meta Information"). These fields would then be displayed on each page. But this would need to be changed for each category and product otherwise the default option would show.

**Rewriting the category/product blocks**

The blocks Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View and Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View contain the functions _prepareLayout(). In this function the title is set via a call to $headBlock->setTitle($title);

If you created your own module and rewrite these blocks, then do what ever you wanted to the title.

config.xml:

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <catalog>
            <rewrite>
                <category_view>Your_Module_Block_Category_View</category_view>
                <product_view>Your_Module_Block_Product_View</product_view>
            </rewrite>
        </catalog>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

**Product view event**

For the product view (sadly not the category view) you could also observer the event "catalog_controller_product_view". At this point you can also change the title on the product.

I would suggest rewriting the blocks as then you would have the same solution for both the category and product.

Comment: I have created a simple extension that provides a wrapper for this observer: https://github.com/mobweb/MobWeb_CustomProductMetaTags